# How to set a custom creation date for OpenPGP certificates?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

Can I create an OpenPGP Certificate containing a custom creation (start validity) Date?

I need to create an OpenPGP certificate today, but made it valid from next week only (for example).

Using tools like "Kleopatra", I'm able to set the "expiry date" only.

Comment: Why would you want this? Also, you could wait a week before exporting the public key, so none is able to use it untill then. Or create the key next week?

Comment: I think setting your computer's clock forward one week will do the trick.

Comment: PGP doesn't use "certificates". Do you mean a public/private key pair? ("Certificate" is often the term used for the signed X.509 public key portion.)

Comment: Thank you all! Every X days we need to create our keys, share PublicKey with our partner and agree on the date we will start to use the it. The time between we create the Keys and our Partner import it in its system could be log. So we need a kind of "StartValidityDate". If i understand well, we have 2 ways: 
1) change the date of O.S. so the "Creation Date" will be also the "StartValidityDate" (but we will not able to change it)
2) when we send our PublicKey to our partner, we will send also the "StartValidityDate" and our partner has to manage the PublicKey and the StartDate. Right? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

### Keys and Certificates

First of all, OpenPGP has a different wording than X.509. What you describe as certificates is usually called "key" in OpenPGP, while only signatures on other keys are called a certification.

### "Not valid before"

Furthermore, there is no defined "not valid before" parameter. There is the creation timestamp, but there is no defined behavior for dates in the future -- implementations of OpenPGP might issue a warning, completely deny using the key or simply ignore the fact at all.

### Faking the Creation Time

GnuPG does not know an option to set the creation time, but the system time is used. The easiest and most general way is to change the system time to the desired date.

For Linux, there is the very helpful tool `faketime` ([source on github](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime)), which can be used to start other commands with arbitrary dates:

```
faketime -f '2008-12-24 08:15:42' gpg2 --gen-key
```

You might have to terminate `gpg-agent` so it gets restarted, if it does not see (but use) the faked time.

GnuPG also has a `--faketime` parameter, but it does only work if `--debug` is also set, which requires some compile options that are not always applied for production builds.

Comment: Perfect. `faketime` is exactly what I was looking for. In Arch Linux, the command is part of `libfaketime`: `sudo pacman -S libfaketime`

Comment: The -f option to faketime is critical, otherwise faketime is smarter than you want it to be and uses the date string to calculate an offset, allowing time to continue flowing, and the actual creation time of the key will depend on how long gpg takes to run.